# Is there a workaround/fix for psql producing eldritch gibberish on Windows in Japanese locale?

Tags: windows, postgresql, locale, psql

I just did a fresh install of Postgres 9.3.5 onto my Windows 7 machine. My machine's locale is "Japanese (Japan)". When I run `psql` at the command prompt (or PowerShell), this happens:

[image]

If I run `psql --help`, the eldritchness increases:

[image]

I get normal output if I switch my locale back to "English (United States)", but this is a time-consuming process that involves restarting my computer.

Question: is there a way to make psql display normal output even when in a Japaese locale; OR, is there a way to switch locales (or make psql believe that I have switched locales) that is fast and does not involve restarting my computer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run in the unicode codepage - `chcp 65001`, or run cmd as `cmd.exe /k chcp 65001`.

For frustrating historical reasons Windows command prompts run in an ANSI codepage by default.